# How to rotate the camera view around a point in OpenGL with gluLookAt

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-compat

I’m trying to use the gluLookAt function to set up the correct view transformation for the camera’s position and orientation. In my program there is a sphere centered in the origin and when the arrows key are pressed the camera moves according (left, right, up and down) around the sphere.

I tried to use this transformation:
gluLookAt(xc, yc, zc, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1,0, 0,0);

To verify its correctness I printed out the three axes. It doesn’t seem to properly work. When I move up and down the y axis doesn’t seem to move.

Can you help understand what is wrong with that transformation?

Answer (score 0):

**Constant `up` vector is wrong !**

When your `xc=0,yc=?,zc=0` (which is when you move up/down in y axis) then your up vector is (anti)parallel to your view direction which means `gluLookAt` can not create 3 perpendicular basis vectors using cross product which it needs for constructing the [transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214).

In such case the up vector should be different ... I usually use dot product

```
if (dot(a,b)/(|a|.|b|)>0.9)
```

to detect near to (anti)parallel vectors and set different one in your case its simplied like this:

```
if (fabs(yc*yc)/(xc*xc+yc*yc+zc*zc)>(0.9*0.9)) use different up vector
```

You can use `(+/-1,0,0)` or `(0,0,+/-1)` which one and which sign depends on your coordinate system conventions (so your view does not twist/mirror/rotate on going through this singularity).

The `0.9` threshold means:

```
cos(da) = 0.9
da = acos(0.9)
da = 25.84 deg
```

which is the max allowed angular difference between the two vectors ...